# How to add an item to an array qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have:

**MyItem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
      property string info1: "info"
      property int info2: 1
}
```

How to add an item to an array qml during initialization?

It's work:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
      property var arr: [{ info1: "test", info2: 1}, { info1: "info" }]
}
```

But, it's not work:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
      property var arr: [MyItem { info1: "test", info2: 1}, MyItem { info1: "info" }]
}
```

Comment: You may be looking for [Dynamic QML Object Creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html)

Comment: All children if an `Item` could be accesed using [Item.children](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) as an array. You have to clarify your question to get an answer. For what you need that?

Comment: @eyllanesc: What for? The parent can be just as well `null`

Answer (score 4):

If you use a newer QML version you can use the new `list<Item>`-type for properties. There you can easily add Items in the syntax you want - just like when you were using a `property alias someProperty: someItem.somePropertyList (e.g. children)` for example.

```
include QtQuick 2.10 // I think 2.9 is sufficient
ApplicationWindow {
    ...
    property list<Item> myItemList: [
        Item { Component.onCreated: console.log(parent) }, // parent will be null! Set it explicitly if needed.
        Item {},
        Item {},
        ...
    ]
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html

Small side note from the documentation:

> **Note**: The list type is not recommended as a type for custom properties. The var type should be used instead for this purpose as lists stored by the var type can be manipulated with greater flexibility from within QML.

*IMHO, you can ignore that as long as you don't need the "greater flexibility"*

---

In older versions this is not possible but you could hack your way around, if you have a type "ArrayObject.qml"

```
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    id: root
    default property QtObject store
    readonly property var arr: (arr === undefined ? [] : arr) // This will give you a binding loop, but ensures that after filling the array, it is not reset to [].
    onStoreChanged: {
        if (store) {
            console.log(store)
            arr[arr.length] = store
            console.log(arr, arr.length)
        }
        store = null
    }
}
```

You can then use it:

```
ArrayObject {
    id: tst
    Item {
    }
    Item {
    }
    Item {
    }
}
```

Of course, there might be other workarounds.

E.g:

```
Item {
    property var myArray: [
         itemId1, itemId2, itemId3, itemId4
    ]
    Item { id: itemId1 }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Dynamic QML Object Creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
      property var arr: {
          component = Qt.createComponent("MyItem.qml");
          item1 = component.createObject(null, {"info1": "test", "info2": 1});
          item2 = component.createObject(null, {"info1": "info"});
          return [item1, item2];
      }
}
```

See [`Qt.createComponent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) and [`createObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method) for more information.